# How can I define a Map using another Map in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, nested, fluttermap

I have a `Map` like following:

```
  final Map<String, dynamic> question = {
    'rating': {
      'added': false,
    }
  };
```

And I want to use it inside another `Map` like below:

```
  final Map<String, dynamic> book = {
    'detail': {
      'questions': [
        question // here I need to have a list of the above Map
      ]
    }
  };
```

But it doesn't work. How can I use another `Map`'s definition inside a `Map` I am gonna define as it's parent?

Comment: Why not classes?

Comment: @Soliev: IDK, maybe because finally I should convert it to JSON and send it back to the server, also convert it from JSON when I receive the data, so I decided to use something more like JSON in the Flutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put the spread operator "..." like this:

```
   final Map<String, dynamic> book = {
'detail': {
  'questions': [...{question}] // here I need to have a list of the above Map
  
}};
```

[EDIT]
try this instead,it should work fine now :

```
 late final Map<String, dynamic> book = {
'detail': {
  'questions': [...{question}] // here I need to have a list of the above Map   
}};
```

Comment: I tried it but it gives me this error as before: `The instance member 'question' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expressiond`

Comment: Yeah it seems it works by now, what does `late` do in this case?

Comment: it's used to wait the initialization of the "question " map so the "book" map won't be null.

Comment: So if `book` had another property and we wanted to access that before the `question` gets initialized, we would get an error?

Comment: yes if you don't put `late` there.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question, but the best way to figured it out is to try to code what you're saying

Comment: BTW it seems I can not reach wath I need with help of Maps. Please have a look at this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75679841/rangeerror-rangeerror-index-invalid-value-only-valid-value-is-0-1

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it works just fine, but as mentioned by @Soliev, it is recommended to use classes instead of plain maps.
Here is an example of how you can use your code with classes.
This is a very simple example, but later on, you can research data classes, toJson, and FromJson methods, and add them to your classes if needed.

```
class Question {
  final Rating rating;
  Question({
    required this.rating,
  });
}

class Rating {
  final bool added;
  Rating({
    required this.added,
  });
}

class BookDetail {
  final List<Question> questions;
  BookDetail({
    required this.questions,
  });
}

class Book {
  final BookDetail detail;
  //You can add more fields 
  //final String name
  //final String author
  Book({
    required this.detail,
  });
}
```

Comment: Why is it recommended to use classes?

Comment: It is recommended to use classes because they provide a blueprint for future objects (such as maps), which helps avoid spelling and value type errors. For example, by using classes instead of maps, you can ensure that you never assign a String to "Rating.added" because it is set to bool. This also makes it easier to create additional ratings in the future since you know that you need to pass a boolean value. These are just a few good reasons to use classes instead of maps.

Comment: Yah, I think I have found another con for using a Map here if I am right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75679841/rangeerror-rangeerror-index-invalid-value-only-valid-value-is-0-1

Comment: Yes, you can use maps, and you probably won't have any issues. However, as I mentioned earlier, using classes allows you to create objects from maps. Researching JSONs, "toJson" and "fromJson" methods will be very useful for you to learn more about maps, objects, and classes.

Comment: I tried the class approach here but I have a problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75688658/why-i-can-not-assign-a-variable-to-a-class-member-variable-in-flutter

Comment: Why do you use `{}` around constructor arguments? Why don't you just do like `Question(
    required this.rating,
  );` instead of `Question({
    required this.rating,
  });` ?  What is the difference?

Comment: I add {} for named arguments instead of positional arguments. You can read more about it here https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-difference-between-named-and-positional-parameters .

Comment: I didn't know we can use named/positional arguments for class constructors as well!

Answer (score 0):

> The instance member 'question' can't be accessed in an initializer.
> Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different
> expression

Use it like this:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late final Map<String, dynamic> question;
  late final Map<String, dynamic> book;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    question = {
      'rating': {
        'added': false,
      }
    };
    book = {
      'detail': {
        'questions': [question, question, question, question]
      }
    };
  }
...
}
```

Comment: Number of questions are unknown( non constant)