# RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1)

Tags: json, flutter, dart, object

I defined a nested `Map` object like following:

```
  late Map<String, dynamic> book = {
    'storeId': '',
    'title': '',
    'images': [image]
  };

   Map<String, dynamic> image = {
    'imageUrl': '',

  };
```

then tried to add 2 new images like following:

```
book['images'][0] = 'url-to-image';
book['images'][1] = 'url-to-image2'; // Error happens here
```

And supposed the `[image] list inside the` Map`will act like a`List images`, But I encountered this error:

> RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0:
> 1)

Why this happened as I declared `'images': [image]` as a `List`?  Does that mean if I want to have a `List` of image I should do something like below?

```
  late Map<String, dynamic> book = {
    'storeId': '',
    'title': '',
    'images': [image, image]
  };
```

What if I don't know the number of `image`s and want the user to be able to add as much as they want?

Does it mean a list inside a Map doesn't behave like a List object like below?

```
List<image> images;
images[0] = 'url'; 
images[1] = 'url2'; //No Error
```

With no need to any initialization like:

```
List<image> images = [ image1, image2];
```

Comment: In dart, array indexes start at 0. So your first image is `book['images'][0]`

Comment: "Why this happened as I declared 'images': [image] as a List? In your own words, if the list is `[image]`, how many things do you think it contains? What do you think are the valid indices for the list? What do you think you should get if you use the index `1` into that list?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I wanted to add a variable to index 1 like what I can do with `List<image>` with no need to initialize it beforehand.

Comment: In your own words, why do you think you are adding it to index 1? (hint: if the error message says `RangeError (index)`, that means it's telling you that the index is wrong, yeah? If it says "Only valid value is 0", what do you suppose it means is the thing that can only be 0? The index, perhaps?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I am new to Flutter and wanted to make sure if I can do what I can do with `List`s by `Map`s or not. I added more detail to my question.

Comment: I've never used Flutter; but in **most** programming languages, anything that calls itself a "list", "array", "vector" etc. that you *index into* by using *integers*, will expect you to start counting at **0, not 1**. It seems like the error message is already explaining this quite clearly.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I think we are not in a same page! I know the indices start from 0. I am asking a different question!

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I added more information to the question hope help you understand what I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

`Only valid value is 0: 1` means it contains a single element on index 0, where you are trying to get index 1. Which is out of range. A safe case I prefer checking the length before accessing index.

```dart
book['images'].length>1? book['images'][1]: yourDefaultValue
```