# How to assign a new variable to the "List<Class>" members in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, variable-assignment, nullable

I have a code like following:

```
var book = Provider.of<Book>(context, listen: false);

ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform
        .pickFiles(
            allowMultiple: false, type: FileType.image
            );

    if (result != null) {
      uploadImageURL =  await s3URLGet(); // Gets a URL
      await s3FileUpload(uploadImageURL!, result); // Uploads the file
  setState(() {
    print(
        'this is upload url ${uploadImageURL!}'); // It works and prints out a correct URL
    book.images?[book.imageIndex].imageUrl =
        uploadImageURL!; //This doesn't work
  });
  print(' this is what uploaded ${book.images?[book.imageIndex].imageUrl}'); // Prints out null
}
```

},
child: Text('Upload image'),
),

***I don't know why it can't assign the variable here?***

```
book.images?[book.imageIndex].imageUrl = uploadImageURL!;
```

And these are the related classes:

```
class Book with ChangeNotifier {
  List<BookImage>? images;

  int imageIndex = 0;

  changeImageIndex(int index) {
    imageIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class BookImage {
  String? imageUrl;
}
```

***I also found out the problem is with the `List` members. For example if I do:***

```
book.imageIndex = 100;
```

***It works!***

Comment: Where is `uploadImageURL` declared?

Comment: It seems evident that `book.image` is `null`, so `book.image?[book.imageIndex].imageUrl = ...` will be short-circuited to never perform the assignment.

Comment: @Renato: The problem isn't with those functions. Those perform their job well and I have the correct URL, etc. The problem is with the assignment part.

Comment: @jamesdlin: So how can I fix that? I remember I had kinda similar code previously that was working fine, but this one doesn't!

Comment: Fix it by figuring out why `book.image` is `null` when you don't expect it to be.  You haven't provided enough information for anybody to figure that out for you. (Furthermore, what code you've provided isn't consistent: you try to access `book.image`, but your `Book` class has an `images` member but no `image` member.)

Comment: @jamesdlin: Sorry `book.image` was a typo and I corrected it. What I try to do in this code is assigning the URL to `imageUrl` propery of `BookImage` class. Then create a List of type this class within the `Book`  class.

Comment: @jamesdlin: I also found out the problem is with the `List` members. For example if I do:

    `book.imageIndex = 100;`

It works!

Comment: @best_of_man You haven't shown any code where `book.images` is ever initialized with a `List` object.  You haven't shown any evidence that it should ever be non-`null`.

Comment: @jamesdlin: Because I never initialized it anywhere! I only created the classes and wanted to assign variables to it. For simple variables it works this way, but for List variable it doesn't, and I am wondering to know why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252424/discussion-between-jamesdlin-and-best-of-man).

Comment: @jamesdlinL Why does it work for `book.imageIndex` but doesn't for `book.images[]`? Even if I change the class definition like `  List<BookImage>? images = [];`  it still doesn't work!

Comment: @jamesdlin: Your solution for using `.add()` function worked and you can write it as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments and in chat, you have:

> ```dart
> book.images?[book.imageIndex].imageUrl = uploadImageURL!;
> ```

But if `book.images` is `null`, then the expression will be short-circuited, and everything after the `?` will be ignored.

And as indicated by your comments, you never assigned anything to `book.images`, so it will *always* be `null`.

> Even if I change the class definition like `List<BookImage>? images = [];` it still doesn't work!

That still won't work because even though `book.images` is no longer `null`, it's now always an *empty* `List`.  Accessing a non-existent element of a `List` won't automatically grow the `List` and won't automatically instantiate an element (a `BookImage`) for you.

You must explicitly instantiate each `BookImage` object and must explicitly add it to the `book.images` list.  If your goal is to do that after the `onPressed` handler is done using the `FilePicker`, then your logic seems a little backward; instead of determining an index and trying to create a `BookImage` object at that index, you should create and add a `BookImage` object and then determine the index of the element you just added.  For example, something like:

```dart
var bookImage = BookImage()..imageurl = uploadImageURL!;
(book.images ??= []).add(bookImage);
```

Note that if you change `book.images` to be non-nullable (and initialize it to an empty `List`) and if you add a `BookImage` constructor, the above can be simplified to `book.images.add(BookImage(uploadImageURL!))`.

Comment: Could you have a look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75730093/how-to-create-a-list-of-videoplayer-widgets-in-flutter